# Make navbar exceed max-width [CSS]

Tags: html, css

Currently experimenting with HTML and CSS and am struggling with this issue.

I'm messing around with a responsive website, and somehow can't make my navigation bar exceed the max-width of my navbar exceed the max-width of my content.

What I'd like it to look like `https://imgur.com/a/KAk9mOi`

I do really hope anyone can help me.
TIA.

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="nav-items">
    <li class="nav-item nav-item--active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```
.main {
}

.navbar {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #1C2826;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.nav-items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.nav-items > li {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;

}

.nav-item:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.nav-item--active {
    /* after */
}

.content {
    padding: 8px;
}

.login-card {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.login {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.login-button {
    background-color: #D64550;
    padding: 4px;
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.login-input {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.footer {
    padding: 8px;
}

.inline-block {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Alt over 460px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 460px) {
    .main{
        max-width: 600px;
    }

    .navigation-items{
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .login-button {
        font-size: inherit;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m0u79e8s/

Comment: Please add the relevent code in a SO code snippet

Comment: Hey and welcome, please avoid using external links and put snippet. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use jsfiddle to show your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is useful

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.main {
}
 
.navbar {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #1C2826;
    width: 100%;
}
 
.nav-items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
 
.nav-items > li {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
 
}
 
.nav-item:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
 
.nav-item--active {
    /* after */
}
 
.content {
    padding: 8px;
}
 
.login-card {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
 
.login {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
 
.login-button {
    background-color: #D64550;
    padding: 4px;
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
}
 
.login-input {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}
 
.footer {
    padding: 8px;
}
 
.inline-block {
    display: inline-block;
}
 
/* Alt over 460px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 460px) {
  .main {
        display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .content {
    max-width: 460px;

  }
 
    .navigation-items{
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
 
    .login-button {
        font-size: inherit;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
 
        <title>Responsive time</title>
       
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./generic.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    </head>
    <html>
        <body>
 
            <main class="main">
 
                <!-- Navigation elements -->
                <nav class="navbar">
                    <ul class="nav-items">
                        <li class="nav-item nav-item--active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
 
                <!-- Section -->
                <section class="content">
                    <h1 class="test">Time to get responsive</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore deleniti, quia provident!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis quas alias reiciendis velit, dolor eos temporibus culpa ex modi itaque nostrum natus doloribus sed maiores, a obcaecati quia sequi quisquam corrupti perspiciatis sit quam, qui expedita. Nemo sed dolor earum voluptate quod reiciendis rem laborum atque ex nulla sapiente ea ullam assumenda, fugiat quae incidunt dicta, cupiditate repellendus possimus aliquid! Ad veniam vero alias, rem quod atque dolores saepe possimus, tempora, eaque magnam culpa animi repellendus ratione dolorem harum quo.</p>
                   
                    <!-- Form -->
                    <div class="login-card">
                        <form class="login" action="#" method="get">
                            <input class="login-input" type="email" placeholder="Indtast email">
                            <input class="login-input" type="password" placeholder="Indtast kodeord">
                            <button class="login-button">Send</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
 
                    <picture>
                      <source media="(max-width:459px)" srcset="img/cow.jpg">
                      <source media="(min-width:460px)" srcset="img/dog.jpg">
                      <img src="/img/cow.jpg" alt="animals">
                    </picture>
 
                </section>
 
                <footer class="footer">
                    <div class="footer-content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit quas beatae voluptate.</p>
                        <a href="#">Some other link</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi!</p>
                        <img class="logo-image" src="/rubbish" alt="">
                    </div>
                </footer>
 
            </main>
        </body>
    </html>
</html>
```